# Change column name in My account > downloads section in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce

I'm trying to change the column name in My Account > Download Section

[image: Download section - column name]

---

`order-downloads.php` template file contains

```php
<?php foreach ( wc_get_account_downloads_columns() as $column_id => $column_name ) : ?>
<th class="<?php echo esc_attr( $column_id ); ?>"><span class="nobr"><?php echo esc_html( $column_name ); ?></span></th>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Do I have to make the adjustment in the foreach loop? any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [`order/order-downloads.php`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.2.0/templates/order/order-downloads.php) template file the following is applied to line [30](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.2.0/templates/order/order-downloads.php#L30)

```php
<?php foreach ( wc_get_account_downloads_columns() as $column_id => $column_name ) : ?>
```

---

`wc_get_account_downloads_columns()` refers to [`wc-account-functions.php`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/wc-account-functions.php), line [234](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/wc-account-functions.php#L214)

```php
/**
 * Get My Account > Downloads columns.
 *
 * @since 2.6.0
 * @return array
 */
function wc_get_account_downloads_columns() {
    $columns = apply_filters(
        'woocommerce_account_downloads_columns',
        array(
            'download-product'   => __( 'Product', 'woocommerce' ),
            'download-remaining' => __( 'Downloads remaining', 'woocommerce' ),
            'download-expires'   => __( 'Expires', 'woocommerce' ),
            'download-file'      => __( 'Download', 'woocommerce' ),
            'download-actions'   => '&nbsp;',
        )
    );

    if ( ! has_filter( 'woocommerce_account_download_actions' ) ) {
        unset( $columns['download-actions'] );
    }

    return $columns;
}
```

---

So to answer your question, you could apply the following

```php
function filter_woocommerce_account_downloads_columns( $columns ) {
    $columns['download-file'] = __( 'New name', 'woocommerce');

    return $columns;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_account_downloads_columns', 'filter_woocommerce_account_downloads_columns', 10, 1 );
```